# Preact-CLI + styled-components. Doesn't re-hydrate

Tags: javascript, styled-components, server-side-rendering, preact

I have a site, built in preact using the cli. On top of this I have a UI-library built with styled-components. I want to achieve a solid SSR implementation.

I've followed the instructions in the styled-components docs regarding SSR.
[styled-components instructions on SSR](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#example)

The page loads, prerendered, however when the javascript kicks in, instead of hydrating existing HTML, it replaces the HTML. This results in the page going blank for .3 seconds.

The example in the docs feel rather inconclusive. Here is how I tried to implement the example:

```
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components';
import { h, render } from 'preact';
import { default as renderToString } from 'preact-render-to-string';
import './style'; // eslint-disable-line
import App from './components/app';

if (typeof window === undefined) {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
    renderToString(sheet.collectStyles(<App />));
    sheet.getStyleElement();
}

if (typeof window !== 'undefined'){
    const FontLoader = require('./FontLoader').default;
    // Loading fonts, defered
    FontLoader();
}

export default App;
```

Anyone who has done this, and is willing to give some hints?

Am on preact-cli 2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve it, had the initial page loaded async. Which caused the issue.